# Program always throws an exception

Tags: java, try-catch

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("E:/My Documents/School Work/Java/popoRecordsTXT.txt"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Nice try nerd, that file doesn't exist! Edit yo code");
    }
}
```

So the problem I'm having is that is catches the exception every single time. I don't know if it's a question with the try-catch or the file path, but yeah. It compiles, but it doesn't run properly.

Comment: Have you narrowed down what the cause of your caught `Exception` is?

Comment: Why not `e.printStackTrace()` so you can tell what went wrong, instead of just insulting yourself and *not* printing what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are catching a general exception

Trying catching like FileNotFoundException or some of the exceptions scanner can throw. Catching an Exception can be literally any exception. It hard to pinpoint the problem unless you try catching specific exceptions

Comment: Turns out it was an error with the text file I was scanning. This was incredibly helpful in narrowing down the possibilities for the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting a `FileNotFoundException`. Try running `edit [file_path]` in Command Prompt, and paste that path, in quotes and with the forward-slashes replaced with back-slashes, and see if it works. That file path has to be wrong. Syntactically, there is nothing wrong with what you have.